# how to change this function from lambda to rds aurora

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

I have this lambda function and as you can see it connects to a Dynamo DBs, what I need to do is this same function to be connected to an RDS aurora DBs, what do I have to change?

```
'use strict;

 

const uuid = require('uuid');

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const logger = require("../components/logger.js");

const errorHandlerModule = require("../components/error-handler.js");

 

const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

 

module.exports.create = (event, context, callback) => {

 

  // Initialization

  const errorHandler = errorHandlerModule();

  logger.init();

 

  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();

  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);

  if (typeof data.text !== 'string') {

    logger.error('Validation Failed');

    

    callback(null, {

      statusCode: 400,

      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },

      body: 'Couldn\'t create the todo item.',

    });

    return;

  }

 

  const params = {

    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,

    Item: {

      id: uuid.v1(),

      text: data.text,

      checked: false,

      createdAt: timestamp,

      updatedAt: timestamp,

    },

  };

 

  // write the todo to the database

  dynamoDb.put(params, (error) => {

    // handle potential errors

    if (error) {

      logger.error(error);

      callback(null, {

        statusCode: error.statusCode || 501,

        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },

        body: 'Couldn\'t create the todo item.',

      });

      return;

    }

 

    // create a response

    const response = {

      statusCode: 200,

      body: JSON.stringify(params.Item),

    };

    callback(null, response);

  });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html

Keep in mind that since RDS exists within your VPC you will need to attach your Lambda to your VPC. And in order to do this your execution role will need to add AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole.